# Sitecore Azure rebuild index:The request is invalid. Details: index.fields[0].name

Tags: azure-search

I am using Sitecore 8.2 update 3 and Azure search service in our application.
I am able to rebuild the master index successfully but when i am rebuilding web index, it will get stuck in middle and never completes.
I get below error in logs:

> WARN Crawler : AddRecursive DoItemAdd failed - {D9B152A2-0503-45EF-ACE0-AAFE117120A7}
>    Exception: System.AggregateException
>    Message: One or more errors occurred.
>    Source: mscorlib
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch batch)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchUpdateContext.Commit()
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor.IndexModified(IProviderUpdateContext context, Object document, IndexOperation operation)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchUpdateContext.AddDocument(Object itemToAdd, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchIndexOperations.Add(IIndexable indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, ProviderIndexConfiguration indexConfiguration)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoAdd(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.HierarchicalDataCrawler`1.CrawlItem(T indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, CrawlState`1 state)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.BadRequestException
>    Message: Error in the request URI, headers, or body
>    Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage response)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.UpdateIndex(IEnumerable`1 fields)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.SyncRemoteService(IEnumerable`1 sourceSchema, IEnumerable`1 incomingSchema)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<EnsureIsInSync>b__0()
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Utils.Retryer.RetryPolicy.Execute(Action action)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.PostDocumentsImpl(ICloudBatch batch)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch batch)
>    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<PostDocuments>b__0(ISearchService searchService)
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.>b__0(Object )
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: >Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException
>   Message: {"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid. Details: >index.fields[0].name : The name field is required.\r\n"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this exception while trying to rebuild sitecore web index.
This issue arises when sitecore tries to index some item whose template or field doesn't exist in the web database.

I got this issue resolved by republishing the templates as some templates were not published properly earlier.